# Hbase: put multiple versions of a row at the same time using JSON

Tags: javascript, json, xml, hadoop, hbase

From [Cloudera Hbase REST API docs](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/admin_hbase_rest_api.html#concept_jmt_sk5_jv__table_n1t_vq5_jv) this is XML structure to `PUT` multiple rows at the same time.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <CellSet>
    <Row key="cm93NQo=">
      <Cell column="Y2Y6ZQo=">dmFsdWU1Cg==</Cell>
      <Cell column="Y2Y6ZQo=">dmFsdWU1Cg==</Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row key="cm93NQo=">
      <Cell column="Y2Y6ZQo=">dmFsdWU1Cg==</Cell>
    </Row>
  </CellSet>
```

**Q: How do I do it using JSON?**

What I've tried so far:

1. With `CellSet` key, having following error:

> Error 500 Unrecognized field "CellSet" (Class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.rest.model.CellSetModel), not marked as ignorable

```js
    {
      "CellSet": {
        "Row": [
          {
            "key": "cm93NQo=",
            "Cell": [
              {
                "column": "Y2Y6ZQo=",
                "$": "dmFsdWU1Cg=="
              },
              {
                "column": "Y2Y6ZQo=",
                "$": "dmFsdWU1Cg=="
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "key": "cm93NQo=",
            "Cell": [
              {
                "column": "Y2Y6ZQo=",
                "$": "dmFsdWU1Cg=="
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

2. Without `CellSet` key, without errors and with only one version per row:

```js
{
   "Row": [
    {
      "key": "cm93NQo=",
      "Cell": [
        {
          "column": "Y2Y6ZQo=",
          "$": "dmFsdWU1Cg=="
        },
        {
          "column": "Y2Y6ZQo=",
          "$": "dmFsdWU1Cg=="
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "key": "cm93NQo=",
      "Cell": [
        {
          "column": "Y2Y6ZQo=",
          "$": "dmFsdWU1Cg=="
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can't insert multiple versions of a row if they will have the same timestamp. In your example data is identified only with row key and a column. I did not work with Cloudera and never used HBase REST api, but according to [source code on github](https://github.com/cloudera/hbase/blob/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/rest/model/CellModel.java#L57), CellModel allows to set cell timestamp. So I suggest to add it to your request:

```
"Row": [
    {
      "key": "myRowKey",
      "Cell": [
        {
          "column": "myColumn",
          "$": "value1",
          "timestamp" : 1473379200
        },
        {
          "column": "myColumn",
          "$": "value2",
          "timestamp" : 1470000000
        }
      ]
    }
```

Also, in your example there are two rows with same key, check that data is correct

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think of that approach. It works as expected.